# Test for .catch(() block fails in Jest

Tags: jestjs, vuex

I am trying to test that a Vuex action's `.catch(()` block is reached given a certain API response, and that it returns the error. The `catch` is reached, but the test fails since it is expecting the actual API response, instead of the error that I throw.

The action that I am testing is:

```
  getPageItems ({ commit, state, }) {
    const page = state.page;
    return testApi.fetch(`${pageNumber}`).then((response) => {
      try {
        isValid(response);
        commit('addItemsToList', response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
  },

   export const isValid = (response) => {
    response.name ? true : throw new Error('invalid item');
};
```

The test I have is:

```
    test('errors caught', async () => {
      const item = {};
      const commit = jest.fn();
      const state = {
       pageNumber: 2,
      };

    testApi.fetch.mockRejectedValue(item);
    expect.assertions(1);
    await getPageItems({ commit, state, }).catch((e) => expect(e).toBe('invalid item');
  });
```

This test fails, as it expects `e` to be `item` (the response), and not the error. I'm not sure why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

`mockApi.get.mockResolvedValue(item)` results in fulfilled promise, none of `catch` callbacks will be called.

`catch` makes `getPageItems` unconditionally resolve with fulfilled promise, another `catch` callback after `getPageItems()` will never be called. It doesn't cause `bad response` error either. `getPageItems` returns a fulfilled promise and conditionally calls `console.error`, this is what needs to be tested.

This test doesn't return a promise, even if a rejection was asserted, it would be ignored. `async..await` is the way to chain promises correctly:

```
  test('errors are caught', async () => {
    mockApi.get.mockResolvedValue();
    jest.spyOn(console, 'error');
    await getPageItems({ commit, state });
    expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith('bad response'));
  });
```

Comment: Thank you-- I made a few adjustments and reposted my code above...my only issue is that I would like to test that .catch((e) actually returns the error thrown, but instead it is returning the API response that is supposed to throw this error.

Comment: *I would like to test that .catch((e) actually returns the error thrown* - tested code doesn't return the error, it only logs it. It returns the response (more precisely, rejects with `item` object) in the test because it wasn't mocked correctly. `then` only handles a resolved promise. If you want an error to be triggered in isValid, make it fail with invalid response that doesn't have `name` property, `mockApi.get.mockResolvedValue()` or `mockResolvedValue({name: null})` will work.

Comment: got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: But even when I do ```mockResolvedValue()``` with an empty object, I get zero assertions in the .catch() block of my test, ie ```  await getPageItems({ commit, state, }).catch((e) => {
      expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith('invalid response');
    });``` I will get zero assertions received

Comment: There shouldn't be `catch` because `getPageItems` doesn't return rejected promise when isValid throws. The code in the answer should work.

Comment: AH, ok! That makse even more sense. Thank you again, much appreciate.